# Application Bar Button States in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-bar

When I clicked Application Bar Button in WP8, the button background changes to be PhoneAccentColor. Is it possible to change its color when I clicked it (pressed state)? 
I use a global AppBar and it's in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Name="myDict">
            <!-- Application Bar template !-->
            <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalAppBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="#f28624"  >
                <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/feature.email.png" Text="new message" Click="ApplicationBarNewMessage_Click" />
                <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="users" Click="Users_Click"/>
                    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="settings" Click="Settings_Click"/>
                    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="about" Click="About_Click"/>
                </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            </shell:ApplicationBar>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479826/how-to-change-the-color-of-application-bar-buttons-when-pressed

Answer (score 2):

WP8 uses two default colors Black and White as a default, but they can be set by defining as ApplicationBar.Foreground,  you can check this post with same question [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479826/how-to-change-the-color-of-application-bar-buttons-when-pressed) hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ForegroundColor` to `#FFFEFEFE` if you want white or any other color in the `appbar`

```
<shell:ApplicationBar ForegroundColor="#FFFEFEFE" BackgroundColor="#FFCB202D">
....
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

If you set it to `White` then it will not help, because as per the msdn doc white is discarded and the default theme color is used to set the feedback of buttons.